# In ZF2, how can I access the Response object inside a controller plugin?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I have a controller plugin that makes a remote call to an authentication service. I want to pass the Set-Cookie headers from this call to my Response in order to pass through the cookies set in the first request to the client's browser.

How can I do this in an controller plugin, where I don't have an available instance of the Resquest/Response class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways.

If your controller plugin extends `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin` you can call (from within your plugin).

```
$this->getController()->getResponse();
```

Another way could be to inject the response object as a constructor argument.

```
// Module.php
public function getControllerPluginConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\FooPlugin' => function($pm) {
                $serviceManager = $pm->getServiceLocator();
                $response = $serviceManager->get('Response');

                return new FooPlugin($response);
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case I was extending AbstractPlugin. Only for the records, the solution for passing through the cookies from the first request was: `$this->getController()->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeaders($response->getHeaders()->get('Set-Cookie'));`